# Could not find me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.13

Tags: android, android-studio, barcode, zxing

I want to use this library into my android studio application https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner. I followed the mentioned step like add library into build.gradle file and add jcenter() but still I have the error "Could not find me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.13".

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

JCenter is deprecated and in read-only mode, therefore you might not find the library you're looking for.

Just use the following code in the `build.gradle` file, sync the project and you're good to go.

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still have the problem. This is error log:

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/1.9.13/zxing-1.9.13.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/1.9.13/zxing-1.9.13.pom
     Required by:   project :app

Answer (score 0):

Use version 1.9.8

```
'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
```

Google "barcodescanner zxing maven" and the related maven library version is expected to appear. Like this:

[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.dm7.barcodescanner/zxing][1]

And here You can see the latest version is 1.9.8 .
[1]: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.dm7.barcodescanner/zxing